# Kernel headers for Kernel module compilation

Tags: linux-kernel, suse, sles

as part of my work I need to fetch kernel headers for all kernel versions for sles.
We use them to compile Kernel objects for our product to run on sles distro.
I have a customer with a specific sles 11 version and I cannot find the relevant Kernel Headers.

I have an account with SUSE and I am searching manually for a specific kernel version headers (RPM files)
The specific kernel version I am searching headers for is sles 11 sp4 3.0.101-108.120.1.x86_64
Unfortunately when I look in https://scc.suse.com/packages I can only see sles sp12 and up

Can anyone please advise as to where can I find the headers for that specific version?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://scc.suse.com/patches and search for the keyword „slessp4-kernel-source-14630“.

It should provide you the download links of all kernel-related packages for the version you‘re searching. My mobile browser showed all download buttons grayed out, so unfortunately I can‘t tell you how to proceed from there.

You probably need to login first. Worst case would be that you’d need a subscription, because SLES 11 SP4 is out of general supports and requires LTSS.